# c++ store a reference to a pure virtual class as member of class

Tags: c++, reference, wrapper, pure-virtual, template-classes

I have a templated wrapper containing an instance of a class which inherits of a pure virtual class.
My problem is how to store the data inside the wrapper.
- I can't use a copy because pure virtual classes can't be instanciated (or sliced if I use a simple virtual class).
- I didn't managed to keep a reference. This ref becomes invalid because I don't manage the allocation of the object I get (out of scope).
- My only solution is to use pointers, even if I wanted to avoid that because that's not really safe and I need my code to be robust.
What can I do?

Here's a little example that simulate my problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

class Module
{
public:
    Module() : m(rand())
    {
        cout << "m = " << m << endl;
    }

    virtual void f() = 0;

    int m;
};

class ModuleA : public Module
{
public:
    ModuleA() : ma(rand())
    {
        cout << "ma = " << ma << endl;
    }

    void f() {}

    int ma;
};

template<typename T>
class Container
{
public:
    Container(T e) : element(e) {}

    T element;
};

// Objects are created outside of main
ModuleA createModule()
{
    return ModuleA();
}

Container<Module&> createContainer()
{
    return Container<Module&>(createModule());
}

int main()
{
    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));

    Container<Module&> conta = createContainer();

    ModuleA& ca1 = dynamic_cast<ModuleA&>(conta.element); // wrong !

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This shouldn't compile. You are binding non-const references to temporary objects.

Comment: This code compile in Visual Studio 2013 without any warning.

Comment: @AntoineLafarge then you're using non-standard extensions (they may be enabled by default in your compiler). You should state the compiler in the question.

Comment: You **can** copy by value, because your `T` is `ModuleA`, which is a concrete class.

Comment: @user2079303 I didn't modified the vc++ compiler or visual studio (community).

Comment: It compiles and links OK for me (VS 2013) too.

Comment: @GiulioFranco No because I store a Module&, and not a ModuleA&. Compuler don't want to copy by value here.

Comment: @AntoineLafarge I'm not suggesting that you did. I'm saying that you're using language features that are not part of c++ and only available in your compiler. That's why you should mention the compiler in the question. Also, regarding your answer to Giulio, you don't have any `Module&` in your code.

Comment: @AntoineLafarge I don't see any `Module&` in your code. The only ref I see is `T& Container<T>::element`, and the only instantiation I see is `Container<ModuleA>`. Just replace `T& element` with `T element` and it works.

Comment: It seems to me this is a question of ownership; something I've also struggled with in the past with C++.   Use unique_ptr for internal ownership, only handing out raw pointers from it to other things you own (encapsulated entities).  Use shared_ptr for things you return to callers, but return them a weak_ptr, the contract being "if I return you a weak_ptr, under no circumstances do you construct a shared_ptr with it and store that instead - I'm responsible for this object".  These are a few things I've learned over the years.

Comment: Increase your warning level: `warning C4239: nonstandard extension used : 'argument' : conversion from 'ModuleA' to 'ModuleA &'`

Comment: @GiulioFranco My mistake, I just updated the code to show what I want to do.

Comment: @AntoineLafarge now I see the problem, and you're no longer using non-standard + bogus C++ extension.

Comment: @GiulioFranco Okay JBL suggested using shared_ptr which is promising.

Comment: @AntoineLafarge I strongly suggest you look into `std::weak_ptr` as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `std::shared_ptr` in your container, i.e.

```
template<typename T>
class Container
{
public:
    // The pointer you get must be managed as well
    Container(std::shared_ptr<T> e) : element(e) {}

    std::shared_ptr<T> element;
};
```

and that would be perfectly safe. Indeed if the object goes out of scope in the code that created it, you still have a valid pointer until the container goes itself out of scope. You can tweak a little further the memory ownership relations with `std::weak_ptr` or `std::unique_ptr` if the semantics of the `std::shared_ptr` don't fit exactly your case.

You should definitely look into `std::weak_ptr`, as it allows you to forbid some code to take ownership of a pointer, but still permits access *if* the pointer is valid at the location where you need to access it. It also prevents memory retain cycles because an `std::weak_ptr` doesn't own the memory.

Comment: @GiulioFranco OP stated that "This ref becomes invalid because I don't manage the allocation of the object I get (out of scope)." so I fairly assumed the wrapper shouldn't be the only owner. That wouldn't be pretty if the container goes out of scope, but the object is still referenced somewhere else through e.g. a raw pointer.

Comment: I would make element private and create a public member function that returns weak_ptr.  I wouldn't return raw pointers from a unique_ptr.

Comment: @Robinson Well then it depends on what OP really needs. Still agree for the last sentence.

Comment: I would recommend shared_ptr<T>, return a weak_ptr<T> from a public method.  Another reason to only return weak_ptr is that it'll help avoid cycles that may result in objects staying alive even though you think they've been destroyed.